# Confused about two types of sub problems in dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

At first i apologize for my bad english.

Recently i am facing some confusing thing about two types of dynamic programming.

In "longest common subsequence" problem if the char is not equal then we take the maximum between two sub problems .
On the other hand " Edit Distance " problem , if the characters is not equal then we take minimum of three sub problems.

My question is why we are take value minimum of three sub problems?
Why we are not take minimum of two sub problems like Longest common subsequence?

Comment: Dynamic programming is just the idea of structuring a solution so that it avoids re-computing subproblems to gain efficiency. That is often by caching, or creating a table of subproblems. Other than that, it's just programming and you have to think about the details to understand why they are as they are -- there's no general rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of choices is different because the nature of the two problems is different.

For the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (which is the edit distance that you are referring to), the three choices correspond to the three possible operations. When computing `lev[i][j]`, corresponding to the substrings `a[1..i]` and `b[1..j]`, and if `a[i] !=  b[j]`, then the three choices are:

- `d[i][j-1]`, which transforms `a[1..i]` into `b[1..j-1]`, then **inserts** `b[j]`;
- `d[i-1][j]`, which transforms `a[1..i-1]` into `b[1..j]`, then **deletes** `a[i]`;
- `d[i-1][j-1]`, which transforms `a[1..i-1]` into `b[1..j-1]`, then **substitutes** `a[i]` with `b[j]`.

If you ignore the third option, then you are computing a different edit distance, one permitting only insertions and deletions. This edit distance is in fact tightly [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Relation_to_other_problems) to the LCS problem. Specifically, if the lengths of the strings are `m` and `n` respectively, then this restricted edit distance will be

```
D = m + n - 2 * LCS(a, b)
```

This equality holds because, in order to transform `a` into `b` using only insertions and deletions, you would have to:

- delete all the characters of `a` except those in the LCS (hence `m - LCS(a,b)` operations);
- insert all the characters of `b` except those in the LCS (hence `n - LCS(a,b)` operations).